# How to write a code to judge if a result is real number or complex number and store it in a vector?

Tags: matlab

If I want to compute a root of quadratic equation as follows:

```
 A=0.07;
 B=1.50+1.31*x_1;
 C=-1.37*x_1+1.08*x_1^2-0.15;
 x_2=(-B+sqrt(B^2-4*A*C))/(2*A)
```

where `x_1` is a parameter and I want to pick `x_1` from a grid `linspace(-1.5,2.5,200)`. If the value of `x_2` is a real number, then I store this value in a vector `ra`, otherwise, `x_2` is a complex, ignore it. Finally, I will get a vector `ra=[x_21, x_22, x_23, ... x_2k]`. I am stuck on how to write a code to accomplish it.

```
   %I try to write such a code as follows but I am confused about this for loop.
   for x_1=linspace(-1.5,2.5,200)
    if isreal(x_2)=1
     ra==x_2
   elseif isreal(x_2)=0
   end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evaluating the quadratic function for all the elements using element-wise operations may be an option. Here I evaluate `x_2` for all indices of the vector/grid elements within `x_1`. After doing this a for-loop can be created to eliminate all the non-real (complex components) using `~isreal` where `~` signifies not/the complement of the function. In this case, it can be read as *if not real*. Here I replace any complex component with the placeholder `NaN` (Not a Number) but you can easily only store the real numbers by the alternative code below this snippet.

### Method 1: Complex Numbers Replaced with NaN (Not a Number) Placeholder

```
x_1 = linspace(-1.5,2.5,200);

A = 0.07;
B = 1.50 + 1.31.*x_1;
C = -1.37.*x_1 +1.08.*x_1.^2 - 0.15;
x_2 = (-B + sqrt(B.^2-4.*A.*C))./(2.*A);
x_2 = x_2.';

for Value = 1: length(x_2)
   
   if ~isreal(x_2(Value)) 
   x_2(Value) = NaN;
   end
    
end

x_2
```

---

### Method 2: Only Real Numbers (Alternative Snippet)

```
x_1 = linspace(-1.5,2.5,200);

A = 0.07;
B = 1.50 + 1.31.*x_1;
C = -1.37.*x_1 +1.08.*x_1.^2 - 0.15;
x_2 = (-B + sqrt(B.^2-4.*A.*C))./(2.*A);
x_2 = x_2.';

Row = 1;
for Value = 1: length(x_2)
   
   if isreal(x_2(Value)) 
   x_2_Result(Row,1) = x_2(Value);
   Row = Row + 1;
   end
    
end

x_2_Result
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**